# Getting the string of the chosen option in a drop down that comes from an entity repository

Tags: symfony

I am trying to pull in a repository into a form in Symfony 3.4 and then use the chosen option when the form is submitted.

Here's the form code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('text', TextareaType::class, [
                'label' => 'Text'
            ])
            ->add('category', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Category::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'query_builder' => function(CategoryRepository $repo) {
                    return $repo->createQueryBuilder('c')
                                ->groupBy('c.name');
                }
            ])
            ->add('subcategory', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Category::class,
                'choice_label' => 'subcategory',
                'query_builder' => function(CategoryRepository $repo) {
                    return $repo->createQueryBuilder('c')
                        ->groupBy('c.subcategory');
                }
            ]);
    }
```

With this I can render the form and it looks good. I can choose the various options in the CategoryRepository.

```
{% block body %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}

        {{ form_label(form.name) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.name) }}

        {{ form_label(form.subcategory) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.subcategory) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.subcategory) }}

 {{ form_end(form) }}
```

On submit, when checking with Xdebug, the category is the object Category. I can see the correct values present (those chosen in the drop down of the form) but I want just the string, e.g. category.name. How do I do that?

Also, it might need a different question, but when I select one of the categories, I'd like the subcategory to be updated to exclude those that don't belong to that chosen category. I realise this may require jquery.

Comment: For your second question with the related choice input-fields take a look at this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html. No jquery required unless only 2 choice-inputs are involved. If you need more you have to use jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm certain there are better ways, but one solution would be to

```
        $category = $data->getCategory();
        $data->setCategory($category->getName());
        $data->setSubcategory($category->getSubcategory());
```

And to exclude the subcategories I use jQuery / JavaScript to retrieve the filtered results from a controller / repository, then remove or add those options in the HTML.